# Toggle option in sidebar widgets

Tags: widgets, register-sidebar

I would like to use toggle option in my sidebar widgets. But my sidebar widgets not generating unique id.
This is my register sidebar code.

```
register_sidebar(array(
        'name' => 'Main Sidebar',
        'before_widget' => '<div class="widget %2$s">',
        'after_widget' => '</div></div></div>',
        'before_title' => '<div class="titlediv">',
        'after_title' => '<a class="dropdown" style="float: right;" href="#%1$s" data-toggle="collapse"><b class="toggleicon"></b></a></div><div id="%1$s" class="collapse in"><div id="%1$s" class="boxdiv">'
    )
```

This is how i'm getting output

```
<div class="widget widget_stc-followers">       
<div class="titlediv">Widget Title<a class="dropdown" style="float: right;" href="#%1$s" data-toggle="collapse"><b class="toggleicon"></b></a></div><div id="%1$s" class="collapse in"><div id="%1$s" class="boxdiv">       
Widget content
</div></div></div>
```

I mean `%1$s` not working in `after_title`. I want to use unique id. So can anyone give me some tips to make it work?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `after_title` does not go through any transformations. In fact only the `before_widget` does:

http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.3.1/wp-includes/widgets.php#L876

However, a little lower you can see that `$params = apply_filters( 'dynamic_sidebar_params', $params );` there's a filter you can hook to do your own filtering.

```
add_filter( 'dynamic_sidebar_params', 'wpse_45418_change_after_title' );
function wpse_45418_change_after_title( $params ) {

    $id = $params[0]['widget_id'];

    if ( $id != 'mywidget' ) return $params;

    global $wp_registered_widgets;
    foreach ( (array) $wp_registered_widgets[$id]['classname'] as $cn ) {
        if ( is_string($cn) )
            $classname_ .= '_' . $cn;
        elseif ( is_object($cn) )
            $classname_ .= '_' . get_class($cn);
    }

    $params[0]['after_title'] = sprintf($params[0]['after_title'], $id, $classname );

    return $params;
}
```

This is the general answer to why your IDs are not getting rendered. From this example, to generate your own unique IDs in the `after_title` key, you would need to do something similar, but provide unique IDs, like so:

```
add_filter( 'dynamic_sidebar_params', 'wpse_45418_change_after_title' );
function wpse_45418_change_after_title( $params ) {

    $id = $params[0]['widget_id'];
    if ( $id != 'mywidget' ) return $params;

    $url = esc_url( 'http://some-url-you-need.com' );
    $uidcollapse = $id.'-unique-id';
    $uidboxdiv = $id.'-another-unique-id';

    // <a class="dropdown" style="float: right;" href="%1$s" data-toggle="collapse"><b class="toggleicon"></b></a></div><div id="#%2$s" class="collapse in"><div id="#%3$s" class="boxdiv">

    $params[0]['after_title'] = sprintf($params[0]['after_title'], $url, $classname, $uidcollapes, $uidboxdiv );

    return $params;
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer. Its very helpful. Can you please tell me why you used `$url` variable?

Comment: According to your `after_title` HTML code you did `<a class="dropdown" style="float: right;" href="#%1$s" data-toggle="collapse">`, where `%1$s` is a URL, so hypothetically I inserted a URL there. `$url = esc_url( 'http://some-url-you-need.com' );`

Comment: Ahh got it.. I added your code in my functions.php file. But i'm not seeing any changes in my sidebar widget output. Is something wrong? And one more thing.. I can assign only `href` value to `$url` variable. What about the other attributes like class,style and data-toggle ?

Comment: @Viruthagiri, please make sure you're actually targeting your widget `if ( $id != 'mywidget' ) return $params;` have you changed this line?

Answer (score 1):

Note: Id needs to be unique and you are trying to set the same id to 2 different div's.

Now id `%1$s` and class `%2$s` attributes only work in the `before_widget` argument as far as i know but you can use to toggle you widgets based on but with a bit more then just `data-toggle="collapse"`.